# Not showing Main Activity after Splash screen

Tags: java, android, xml, splash-screen

I under stand the thousand of people saying "don't use a splash," I get it, but the app is not that big, I just want to know what I am doing wrong I think it is something with my Manifest but after my splash shows and when its supposed to go to main page, I get error "Sorry! The Application Grifball (process com.grifball.info) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Here is my Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.grifball.info"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <activity android:name="Splash">
                    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>       
    <activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.grifball.info.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my Splash's Java

```
package com.grifball.info;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle startup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(startup);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            try{
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.grifball.info.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
            }
        }

    };
    timer.start();
}

}
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/splashbg">


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Log Cat

```
04-03 02:39:20.527: D/AndroidRuntime(318): Shutting down VM
04-03 02:39:20.527: W/dalvikvm(318): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.grifball.info/com.grifball.info.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at com.grifball.info.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-03 02:39:20.537: E/AndroidRuntime(318):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the "AndroidManifest.xml", you should change this:

```
<action android:name="com.grifball.info.MAINACTIVITY" />
```

To This:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
```

And, in "Splash.java", you should change:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.grifball.info.MAINACTIVITY");
```

To this:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: I think @IssacZH's `Handler` suggestion is an improvement over the original `Thread` approach. Plus, `finish()` -ing your `Splash` screen is a nice touch.

Comment: Then, we must see your LogCat and hopefully read the exception name, line of code of the crash, and please show us that line of code. It is possibly in Splash.java or MainActivity.java.

Comment: What is line 27 of MainActivity.java? There is a `typeface` problem with one of your `TextView` fonts, perhaps.

Comment: Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),

Comment: Please comment out that line of code and allow whatever uses it to use the default typeface instead. After you get your `MainActivity` working, then you can come back and try to readdress the typeface issue.

Comment: Yea it worked, I used issacs method too. I think it would still work with my method but Haven't tried. I knew that the typeface wasn't working but it didnt show an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the following changes

```
<activity android:name=".Splash">
                <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>       
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

</activity>

finally{
            Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the below code a try, it should work.

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 2000);
}

}
```